# Writing values from dictionary to csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have two csv files that I need to compare and write to a new output file.  I have this part working with one exception.  I converted the first csv file to a dictionary then compare a column from the second csv file to the dictionary key to look for a match.  The problem I'm having is my dictionary has a single key with multiple values.  When I write the values to the new csv file, I get the tuple in a single column but I need them to be in separate columns.

My code is below.

```
d_csv2 = {}

with open('subscriber_info 02212018.csv', 'r') as f_csv2:
    csv_2 = csv.reader(f_csv2)
    for cols in csv_2:
        d_csv2[cols[1]] = cols[0], cols[2]


with open('subscribersWithMultipleDevices.csv', 'r') as f_csv1, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_1 = csv.reader(f_csv1)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Customer', 'Email', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Serial Number', 'WAN MAC', 'IP ADD', 'Model',
                        'Last Contact', 'Circuit ID', '\n'])

    for cols in csv_1:
        try:
            if cols[6] in d_csv2:
                csv_output.writerow(cols + [d_csv2[cols[6]]])
        except KeyError:
            print('key error')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "unpack" the tuple so that you're adding the tuple's contents to the list instead of the tuple itself. You can use the unpack operator (*) to accomplish this.

```
csv_output.writerow(cols + [*d_csv2[cols[6]]])
```

Notice the added `*` before `d_csv2[cols[6]]`.

Comment: Works perfect.  Thank you.